# Webpack 5: assets folder is generated only after the second npm run dev command

Tags: webpack, assets, webpack-5

I'm just starting to use Webpack and now I'm trying to set up my project using Webpack 5 and its new feature: asset modules for fonts(tf|woff|woff2|eot|otf) and images(png|jpg|gif|svg). The project  builds sucessfully: I get dist/main.css, dist/main.js, dist/index.html. All images and fonts files are emitted within the output dist directory with [hash][ext][query] filename.

My project tree is :

```
webpack.config.js
dist
src
--css
--fonts
--img
--index.html
--index.js
```

My webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');

const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CssMinimizerWebpackPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin'); 
const TerserWebpackPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const IS_DEV = NODE_ENV === 'development';
const IS_PROD = !IS_DEV;

module.exports = {
mode: NODE_ENV ? NODE_ENV : 'development',
entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
output : {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: './',
    // assetModuleFilename: 'assets/[hash][ext][query]',
},

module: {
    rules: [

        {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: 'html-loader'
        },

        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                {
                loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, //instead of style-loader
                options: {
                    publicPath: './'
                    },
                },
                'css-loader'
                ],
        },

        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
            type: 'asset/resource',
            // generator: {
            //  filename: 'images/[hash][ext][query]'
            // }
        },

        {
            test: /\.(ttf|woff|woff2|eot|otf)$/,
            type: 'asset/resource',
        },
    ],
},

plugins:
[
    new CleanWebpackPlugin({
        cleanStaleWebpackAssets: false
    }),

    new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
        template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.html'),
        minify: {
            collapseWhitespace: IS_PROD,
        }
    }),

    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
],

optimization: {
    minimizer: [
        new CssMinimizerWebpackPlugin(),
        new TerserWebpackPlugin(),
    ],
},

devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    hot: true,
}
```

}

**Problem #1**: When I set assetModuleFilename: 'assets/[hash][ext][query]' to the output in my webpack config

```
module.exports = {
mode: NODE_ENV ? NODE_ENV : 'development',
entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
output : {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: './',
    assetModuleFilename: 'assets/[hash][ext][query]',
},
```

and run build (npm run dev) FIRST time I get error.

```
 Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'E:\WEB\MiTravel\MiTravel\dist\assets\0a04460c0a144cf3f0a9.svg'
at Object.lstatSync (fs.js:1077:3)
at Function.rimrafSync [as sync] (E:\WEB\MiTravel\MiTravel\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:299:24)
at E:\WEB\MiTravel\MiTravel\node_modules\del\index.js:65:11
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at module.exports.sync (E:\WEB\MiTravel\MiTravel\node_modules\del\index.js:57:40)
at CleanWebpackPlugin.removeFiles (E:\WEB\MiTravel\MiTravel\node_modules\clean-webpack-plugin\dist\clean-webpack-plugin.js:198:37)
```

At this moment there are sucessfully built main.js, index.html, main.css and NO dist/assets dir in the output dist directory. Then I just repeat (SECOND time) npm run dev command and get dist/assets dir with all assets files and main.js, index.html, main.css in the output dist directory. And all fonts and images are ok.

I googled the error, tried to change different parametres but I still can't fix this bug.

Thank you in advance for help and advice.

Answer (score 1):

i am using it using the same first name and it is working.

```
assetModuleFilename: 'assets/[hash][ext][query]'
```

```
generator: {
        filename: 'assets/[hash][ext][query]'
```

try to change `assets` to `images` an see if it works.